# How to get values of selected row in a 2d array excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store the values of the selected row in a dynamic 2d array.

```
Dim values() As Variant
values=ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
```

I am new to VBA.I have data in rows and columns.I want to store all the values of a particular selected row in an array and then plan to further use those values.

Comment: What data does your cell contain? Are there any delimeters? In general your question is very vague and could use some editing. Specifically to adhere to [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Different cells of the row have different data values such as string,integer

Comment: Provide an actual example of the input data. I'm not asking for the data type, I'm asking to determine your delimeter so it can be `split` into an array!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Sub Test()

Dim COL As Long, X As Long, Y As Long
Dim MyArray() As Variant

COL = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For X = 1 To COL
    ReDim Preserve MyArray(Y)
    MyArray(Y) = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, X).Value
    Y = Y + 1
Next X

For X = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    Debug.Print MyArray(X)
Next X

End Sub
```